# OpenAPI returns null in nested type

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, openapi

I have SpringBoot app with Mybatis and Rest API made by OpenAPI
Here is my swagger file:

```
 /api/v1/getdata:
    get:
      summary: ttttttt
      tags:
        - "API"
      description: ttttttt
      operationId: getdata
      parameters:
        - name: sap
          in: header
          required: true
          description: ttttttt
          schema:
            type: string
        - name: created
          in: header
          required: true
          description: ttttttt
          schema:
            type: string
      responses:
        "200":
          description: Success
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/MyResponse'
        "404":
          description: Not Found
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/MyResponse'

components:
  schemas:    
    MyResponse:
        description: ttttttt
        type: object
        properties:
        code:
            description: ttttttt
            type: string
        body:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/MyMetaData'
    
    MyMetaData:
      description: ttttttt
      type: object
      properties:
        id:
          description: id
          type: string
        somedata:
          description: ttttttt
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/MyData'
    
    MyData:
      description: ttttttt
      type: object
      properties:
        id:
          description: id
          type: string
        group:
          description: ttttttt
          type: string
```

Here is my controller code:

```
@Override
public ResponseEntity<MyResponse> getdata(String sap, String created) {
    MyResponse myResponse = new MyResponse();
    try {
        OffsetDateTime date = OffsetDateTime.parse(created, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME);
        Optional<MyMetaData> optionalMetaData = Optional.ofNullable(this.MyMetaDataMapper.getdata(sap, date));
        if (optionalMetaData.isPresent()) {
            myResponse.setBody(optionalMetaData.get());
            myResponse.setCode("OK");
        }
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(myResponse);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(myResponse);
    }
}
```

Here is generated model:

```
@javax.annotation.Generated(value = "io.swagger.codegen.v3.generators.java.SpringCodegen", date = "2022-03-01T12:24:46.999519+03:00")
public class MyMetaData   {
  @JsonProperty("id")
  private String id = null;

  @JsonProperty("somedata")
  private MyData somedata = null;

  public MyMetaData id(String id) {
    this.id = id;
    return this;
  }
```

When I use time MyData like this, as a result i get null:

```
  somedata:
      description: ttttttt
      $ref: '#/components/schemas/MyData'
```

When somedata is of type string, then I get some normal data from my database. What's the correct way to use object type here?

Comment: I see no path for your controller. How is it going to be called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OpenAPI swagger file that you have shared has `$ref: '#/components/schemas/MyData`' but `components` and `schema` is missing in the paths of MyData.

As per Open API [documentation](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/adding-examples/)  it should be

```
components:
  schemas:
    User:    # Schema name
      type: object
      properties:
        id:
          type: integer
          format: int64
          example: 1          # Property example
        name:
          type: string
          example: New order  # Property example
```

For nested objects there is already a [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54803837/openapi-required-property-in-nested-objects-not-working) question which might help. Github [issue](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor/issues/1952).

You can try something similar

```
components:
  schemas:
    MyMetaData:
      type: object
      description: ttttttt
      properties:
        id:
          description: id
          type: string
        somedata:
          description: ttttttt
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/MyData'
    MyData:
      type: object
      description: ttttttt
      properties:
        id:
          description: id
          type: string
```

If you still face issue with OpenAPI swagger you can try [SpringDoc](https://springdoc.org/) . It supports `OpenAPI 3+` and generates Swagger documentation easily. You can find a lot of examples over web.

Sample:  [Baeldung OpenAPI](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-openapi-documentation)   [Dzone SpringDoc OpenApi](https://dzone.com/articles/doing-more-with-springdoc-openapi)

Comment: It was a type( In a real code I have components: schemas:, but still face the same problem(

Comment: Does your code work as expected when using tools like Postman? Else it might be a code issue. Is your expectation here is to generate swagger documentation ? Please clarify, it will help in getting the root cause.

Comment: Are you generating clients from swagger ?